# Java /Selenium- How to check if the download was completed in the download folder

Tags: java, http, selenium-webdriver, download, wait

I have referred many sites, none of them worked for me to check if download was completed 100%

Scenario- I am downloading a file, and I want my selenium/Java program to wait until the download is completed 100%.

(Downloading through HTTP would be the best, but I did not find anything appropriate that would help me out)

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me,
There are 2 ways:

**1st Method:(You need to download AsyncHttpClient JAR)**

```
try {
              AsyncHttpClient client = Dsl.asyncHttpClient();
              final FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
              client.prepareGet(FILE_URL).execute(new AsyncCompletionHandler<FileOutputStream>() {

                    @Override
                    public State onBodyPartReceived(HttpResponseBodyPart bodyPart) 
                      throws Exception {
                        stream.getChannel().write(bodyPart.getBodyByteBuffer());
                        return State.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public FileOutputStream onCompleted(Response response) 
                      throws Exception {
                        return stream;
                    }
                });

        } 
          catch (Exception  e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**2nd Method :**

```
private static void startDownload(String FILE_URL, String FILE_NAME)
 {
     try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(FILE_URL).openStream());
              FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME)) {
                byte dataBuffer[] = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = in.read(dataBuffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {

                    fileOutputStream.write(dataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }
 }
```